# How to change dirrection gradient in shader?

Tags: android

I set shader like this

```
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT));
```

[image]

On Image gradient depend on height. The line ffrom bottom to top changes its color, from blue to red.
What i want - color still should be dependent on height, but whole line from bottom to top has to have same color. E.g vertical line from toopest point should be red on whole it length.
How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can find something easy to implement. But anyway you have to use another constructor for gradient then:

```
LinearGradient (float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, int[] colors, float[] positions, Shader.TileMode tile)
```

And the color should change width-way, but you have to fill **colors** array with colors according points on your graph. But in that case you should calculate your own Color based on value on graph.

You can use *HSVToColor* function to calculate colors:

```
float hoffset = 240;

float h = yourvalue + hoffset; // Those value should be not more than 360, so yourvalue should be reduced to 0 (Blue) till 120 (Red)
float s = 1.0f;
float v = 1.0f;

float[] hsv = {h, s, v};

Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
```

Cannot help further while not seeing your code.

Comment: I updated my question to make it a bit less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters for the object you are using is: x0,y0,x1,y1

You have told it to start at 0,0,0,height
But it seems like what you want is: 0,0,width,0

```
int width = yourObject.getWidth();
new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, 0, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

[Android LinearGradient Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html)

Comment: I updated my question to make it a bit less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set gradient mode to `Shader.TileMode.CLAMP`, then you should try matrix transitions. For example

```
LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height, Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(0, 100);
matrix.postScale(1f, 0.75f);
gradient.setLocalMatrix(matrix);  

paint.setShader(gradient);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to not use the LinearGradient at all. You should compute color values going from blue to red, store them in an array. And then depending on the current height you use the colors stored. You can modfiy this solution to fit for your own height and width if they can change.

```
int colorHeight = aHeight; // number of pixels. Should be the height of your view.
int[] shadeColors = new int[colorHeight];
float step = 255/colorHeight;

// Defining colors going from blue to red: 00 00 FF to FF 00 00
int blue = 255;
int red = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < colorHeight; i++){
    shadeColors [i] = Color.rgb(red, 0, blue - red);
    red+=step;
}
```

This will give you your gradient shading effect from blue to red. You will have to use this array of colors for what ever height you have just stop at the right index.

example if you have an array of heights or of bars to show. Lets say you declared them somewhere to be int[] bars;

```
for(int i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < bars[i]; j++){
        colorArray[bars[i]][j] = shadeColors [j];
    }
}
```

Here you go.